# How can I solve this error "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare retrieve_password()"

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting a error message when accessing 'wp-login.php' page and do not know how to fix it:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare retrieve_password() (previously declared in E:\Inetpub\vhosts\winningbizzness.com\httpdocs\wp-login.php:311) in E:\Inetpub\vhosts\winningbizzness.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\user.php on line 2671`

[image]

Comment: You're going to want to go to those files and lines and see what code is there. Did you change it? It seems like you've got a single function (retrieve_password) declared twice and PHP does not like that. More on that at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131726/redeclare-function-override#:~:text=PHP%20cannot%20redeclare%20functions.,approach%2C%20like%20filters%20or%20similar.&text=PHP%20doesn't%20allow%20to,write%20a%20more%20flexible%20functions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here and it was caused by a WordPress update failure where some files were missing or corrupted.

I quickly resolved just **reinstalling WordPress**. In my case I used FTP, as in this guide: https://kinsta.com/blog/reinstall-wordpress/

Hope it helps anyone reading this answer!